# how to convert post values into uppercase letters in for loop

Tags: php

This is my save function code. inside this there is a for loop i want
 to convert all the post values in uppercase letters. plz help me.
And also suggest how to secure more to this function.
thanks.

```
function save($table, $fields, $condition = '')
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $table SET ";
        if($condition != '')
            $sql = "UPDATE $table SET ";            
        //print_r($fields);exit;        
        $table_fields = $this->get_table_fields($table);

        foreach($fields as $field=>$value)
        {
            if(in_array($field,$table_fields))
                $sql .= "$field = '".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."', ";    
        }
        $sql = substr($sql, 0 ,-2);
        if($condition != '')
            $sql .= " WHERE $condition";
            //print_r($sql);exit;       
        $result = mysql_query($sql);        
        if(mysql_affected_rows())
            return true;        
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: would it be worth googling for `php uppercase character` ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php ... next time you should search on `php.net` first :).

Answer (score 1):

simply concatenate strtoupper() to your value...
just like below...

```
    foreach($fields as $field=>$value)
    {
        if(in_array($field,$table_fields))
            $sql .= "$field = '".strtoupper(mysql_real_escape_string($value))."', ";    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtoupper(your string)`

Check [strtoupper()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php)

Answer (score 0):

do with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

`$upperCased = array_map('strtoupper' $given_array);`

eg:

```
$arr = ['a'=>'alpha', 'b'=>'beta','c'=>'charlie'];
$Arr = array_map('strtoupper',$arr);
var_dump($Arr);
```

will return

```
array (size=3)
  'a' => string 'ALPHA' (length=5)
  'b' => string 'BETA' (length=4)
  'c' => string 'CHARLIE' (length=7)
```

**Note:** `$arr` and `$Arr` are different

#### Reference:

Comment: What if `$_POST = array('a' => 'x', 'b' => 'x')`?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to replace

```
    foreach($fields as $field=>$value)
    {
        if(in_array($field,$table_fields))
            $sql .= "$field = '".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."', ";    
    }
```

With:

```
    foreach($fields as $field=>$value)
    {
        if(in_array($field,$table_fields))
            $sql .= "$field = '".strtoupper(mysql_real_escape_string($value))."', ";    
    }
```

Comment: You are welcome @user3821226! But i think a better way to say thanks here for the useful answers is by doing Up Vote and accepting the most valued answer :)